# Guideline for Asset Slicing for Material Design

Tags: android, material-design

I am working on project based on Material design, which is my first app for Material design as well.
I wanted to know, what is the best way to provide icons & assets to developer.
Firstly i shared icons with him now he is saying that he will need icon with circular background & shadow but in this case asset will have a static shadow?
Another case, he wants icon with blank interaction space so he can put ripple effect over it?

Comment: the ripple effect comes when user touches the screen. you must concentrate on designing when there is no touch involved. the ripple effect can be achieved by developer wherever applicable i.e. buttons, icons, images, list items, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you're using features of Android Lollipop or not. Android 5.+ gives tools to generate shadows, ripples and change tint colors dynamically. It means that you can focus on designing flows and drawing icons, while you can leave all boring stuff to be done by the framework. Spacing and non-standard hit areas can be done from code as well. To make a blank space around a button clickable, play with 'isTransformedTouchPointInView' and 'getHitRect'.

In case you're targeting older devices with no support for MD, you have two options:

1. Consider using simple backgrounds instead of ripples, draw shadows manually, use png icons instead of vectors, etc. While not flashy, such approach would give you a chance to create an app compatible with more devices without having to cut all the graphics manually.
2. Use a backport library. There are pretty good libraries with support for shadows, ripples, custom drawing order, MD components, etc.